# Pipenv - How to specifically tell a package to not be installed

Tags: python, pip, pipenv

Is there a way to get pipenv to uninstall a specific dependeny to a package? I'm working with an ML python package, and one of the dependencies is [rt-utils](https://github.com/qurit/rt-utils). rt-utils has the package dataclasses listed as a dependency, which is kind of incorrect because that package has been included in python since 3.6, but rt-utils has it as a dependency for all python versions. Now, I am on windows and have an error that basically means the existence of this dataclasses package derails stuff, similar to the error [observed by these other people on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71991891/pip-gives-an-attributeerror-module-typing-has-no-attribute-classvar). The error goes away if I delete dataclasses, but I would like to teach pipenv to simply not install dataclasses, which is useful for sending this to other people. I also put up a PR on rt-utils suggesting that they could make the dataclasses package dependent on python 3.6 or less, but I was wondering if there was anything I could do to pipenv that basically tells it: Under no condition should you install dataclasses(Python version for this package is greater than 3.6, it is included). pipenv uninstall dataclasses does not work like this, it doesn't actually do anything since the pipfile just relocks and assumes it needs dataclasses as a dependency(which is fair, since it is listed as a dependency for rt-utils). Does anything like this exist on pipenv?

Comment: I don't know the way to do this, but have you thought about forking their repo , add ``Conditional Dependencies `` and use your forked package ?